# Custom Report Processor with Puppet 5

Tags: puppet, monitoring, zabbix, puppet-enterprise

I am trying to integrate this (https://github.com/shamil/puppet-zabbix-reports/) custom reporting module with puppet 5 master-agent setup. But only the Puppet agent process item is showing (after changing the regular expression in tempalte). Other fields are coming blank. These are my configurations:

- I am using a zabbix server box: zabbix.localdomain
- A puppet agent box: puppetagent.localdomain
- A puppet master box: pupmaster.localdomain

On Master: /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf

```
[master]
reports=zabbix
vardir = /opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver
logdir = /var/log/puppetlabs/puppetserver
rundir = /var/run/puppetlabs/puppetserver
pidfile = /var/run/puppetlabs/puppetserver/puppetserver.pid
codedir = /etc/puppetlabs/code
autosign=true
environmentpath=/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments
dns_alt_names=pupmaster,pupmaster.localdomain
storeconfigs = true
storeconfigs_backend = puppetdb
[agent]
report=true
server=localhost
environment=devl
```

On agent:

```
[main]
report=true
server=pupmaster.localdomain
[agent]
environment=devl
```

On master and agent I have placed the zabbix.yaml file: /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/zabbix.yaml

```
---
# specify zabbix servers to send to
:zabbix_hosts:
  - address: zabbix.localdomain
    port: 10051
```

Zabbix agent is running on all the machines and working.

What could be the issue??

Comment: This module has not been updated since 5 came out. I would assume it is incompatible.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Its working with a mesterless setup. Thats why I am trying with master-agent setup.

Comment: I don't understand how your comment relates to mine.

Comment: @MattSchuchard As you said you are assuming that its incompatible. So, I said Its working with puppet 5 master-less setup. Apologies for any miscommunication.

Comment: You mean the parser and the agent. There are other components, such as server, db, etc. that may be incompatible. I would recommend opening an issue on the github asking about compatibility with 5.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thanks!